# Ruby on RailsでStaticPagesコントローラの生成ができません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Macbook AirでRuby on Railsの開発をしております。
[Ruby on Rails チュートリアルの3章](http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/static-pages?version=4.0#code-pages_controller_spec_title)を勉強中ですが、StaticPagesコントローラを生成しようとするとエラーが出ています。

```
rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework
```

と入力すると下記のようなエラーが出力されます。

```
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.0/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:
    in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
```

何が原因で、これを解消するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

ちなみに開発環境はrubyのバージョンは2.2.1p85、railsのバージョンは4.2.4でrbenvを使っております。
Ruby on Rails チュートリアルの環境はrubyは2.0.0、Railsは4.0.5でRVMを使っています。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、sass-railsにバージョンを指定してあげる必要があると思われます。
Gemfileに`gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.3'`を追加してみてはいかがでしょうか。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716284/uninitialized-constant-sassscript-nameerror

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。やってみましたが、変化ありませんね...同じエラーが出てます。

Comment: `Gemfile`を書き換えてから`bundle install`は行いましたか？

Answer (score 1):

`RVM`を使っているとありますが、ディレクトリ構成が`rbenv`の物なので、
どちらか片方をアンインストールして見ては如何でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

rails tutorialをやるときは必ずバージョンを揃えてやったほうがいいですよ！
僕も最新のバージョンでやってたりしてたんですが、エラーでまくりで、
本質じゃないところで躓きます・・。
Rubyのバージョンを切り替えてから、新しくやるほうがいいかもしれません。
[バージョンを指定してrails newする方法](http://qiita.com/itkrt2y/items/243a89472fa82d60d0ad)

とりあえず、bundle update sass-railsやってみてはどうですか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
「バージョンを指定してrails newする方法」に従ってバージョン指定し新しいアプリケーションを作るようにしましたが、できませんでした。
また、「bundle update sass-rails」を実行しましたが、同じエラーが出ますね..

Comment: rubyのバージョンも合っていますか？